# TypeError: causal_conv1d_fwd(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: pytorch, mamba-ssm

I'm having this error with `mamba-ssm` module:

```
TypeError: causal_conv1d_fwd(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:     1. (arg0: torch.Tensor, arg1: torch.Tensor, arg2: Optional[torch.Tensor], arg3: bool) -> torch.Tensor  Invoked with: tensor([[[ 0.4762, -0.0323, -0.8240,  ...
```

while I run this test code to see if `mamba-ssm` works:

```
import torch
from mamba_ssm import Mamba
batch, length, dim = 2, 64, 16
x = torch.randn(batch, length, dim).to("cuda")
model = Mamba(
    # This module uses roughly 3 * expand * d_model^2 parameters
    d_model=dim, # Model dimension d_model
    d_state=16,  # SSM state expansion factor
    d_conv=4,    # Local convolution width
    expand=2,    # Block expansion factor
).to("cuda")
y = model(x)
assert y.shape == x.shape
```

I've tried to follow this [guide](https://github.com/state-spaces/mamba/issues/40#issuecomment-1849095898) but nothing changed. Both `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc -V` works and this are their outputs:

```
Thu Mar 21 12:20:23 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P0    N/A /  N/A |     11MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1605      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2186      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue simply uninstalling `causal-conv1d` after the rebuilding of `mamba` following the istruction of this [answer](https://github.com/state-spaces/mamba/issues/40#issuecomment-1849095898).